# Trying to replace a pattern with another one

Tags: linux, bash, awk

this is my first question on this website.(glad i found out about this community)

I am trying to replace a specific pattern in a file(multiple lines) that looks somehow like this:

```
Bla bla bla bla |SMTH AWESOME INSIDE >>> LOL| bla bla bla | let's do it again >>> AWESOME |
```

Into a format that looks like this

```
Bla bla bla bla ( LOL | SMTH AWESOME INSIDE ) bla bla bla ( AWESOME | let's do it again )
```

I tried doing this by using a code that parses the line word by word and if it finds out the "|" character starts creating a string that contains the first word,then, after it finds the >>> character it starts creating the second string till it finds the "|" last character, but it didn't work.

I also tried afterwards using AWK(but since i am new to linux i failed as well.

```
awk -F 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { sub(/.*<<</,"", $2); }1' $1 }'
```

and then parse the output with sed(removing the ) and ( characters from both strings. But it didn't work.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Don't use the term "pattern" as its extremely ambiguous. Are you searching for a regexp or a string or something else? If you don't want the `(` and `)`, just don't add them i the first place. Post a FEW lines of sample input (including the cases you think will be hard to get right) and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With extended regexp in **sed**:

```
sed -r 's/\|([^|]+)[[:space:]]*>>>[[:space:]]*([^|]+)\|/( \2 | \1 )/g' File
```

**Logic:**

We look for a pattern which starts with `|` followed by a sequence of non-`|` characters followed by  `>>>` followed by a sequence of non-`|` characters again. See the groupings done with `(` and `)`. Then we substitute these patterns according to our need. `( \2 | \1 )` is the replacement pattern where \1 and \2 are the first and second groupings respectively.

With basic regexp in **sed**:

```
sed 's/|\([^|]*\)[[:space:]]*>>>[[:space:]]*\([^|]*\)|/( \2 | \1 )/g' File
```

Comment: Tried using this method,it works for all lines from a file except the last one(or the first one if it's the only line in the file). How can I modify it to work in all cases? For example,in this case it doesn't work [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/q5rmm5iD)

Comment: Hi, i'm not able to see your input file contents (only outputs)... can u show me the line where it's not working? i'll chk

Comment: It doesn't work on a line that contains only the string that needs to be replaced,in other cases it works perfectly.(For example,if i will have a last line that contains only "|SMTH AWESOME INSIDE >>> LOL| bla bla bla |" it will not transform it. (But if there are other lines before this one it will transform it,no mather their format)

Comment: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hWLyd7aY) , works for line 1,2 but not for the 3rd one.

Comment: @AlwaysGoingToAsk you are now peeling the onion because you didn't paste multiple lines of sample input as I posted in my original comment so we're trying to produce solutions that work for THE one line you posted and can't possibly guess what other forms your input might take, if any.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is just a simple substitution within each line so all you need is sed:

```
$ sed 's/| *\([^|]*\) >>> \([^|]*\) *|/( \2 | \1 )/g' file
Bla bla bla bla ( LOL | SMTH AWESOME INSIDE ) bla bla bla ( AWESOME  | let's do it again )
```

You can do the same in GNU awk with gensub() or other awks with match() and substr().

Answer (score 1):

Perl's regular expressions have a "non-greedy" matching feature that awk's do not:

```
perl -pe '
    s/ \|       # the first delimiter
       (.*?)    # capture up to ...
       >>>      # the middle delimiter
       (.*?)    # capture up to ...
       \|       # the last delimiter
    /($2 | $1)/gx
' file
```

```
Bla bla bla bla ( LOL | SMTH AWESOME INSIDE ) bla bla bla ( AWESOME  |  let's do it again )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'NR%2{ printf("%s", $0) } NR%2==0{ printf("( %s %s",$NF,RS); gsub(/>>>.*$/,")"); printf("%s",$0) }' RS='|' file
Bla bla bla bla ( LOL | SMTH AWESOME INSIDE ) bla bla bla ( AWESOME | let's do it again )
```

The `RS` defines `|` as record separator. So when the input record number (NR) isn't module of 2 (`NR%2` return 1) then print that record itself. If the `NR` is module of 2 (`NR%2==0` means if record is module of 2), then print a single open parentheses followed by printing last field from it and print record separator (`printf("( %s %s",$NF,RS)`), then replace `>>>.*$` with close parentheses and print the rest of record (`gsub(/>>>.*$/,")"); printf("%s",$0)`)

Comment: Never do `printf $0` as you'll get a nasty surprise if the input contains printf formatting characters, e.g. `%s`. Always do `printf "%s", $0` instead. Ditto with the individual fields.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah, I will never forget that. fixed, thank you